# Lista simple dentro de otra lista?

Tags: java

Buenas! Estoy haciendo un ejercicio donde tengo una lista simple de objetos y quiero agregar a cada objeto de esa lista otra lista, ya sea simple o doble?

por ejemplo:

```
  public class Lista_Simple {

  Nodo Primero;
  int Longitud;
  frmEstudiante es = new frmEstudiante();

  public Lista_Simple() {
    Primero = null;
  }

  public boolean isVacio() {
    return Primero == null;
  }

  public void Ingresar(Miembro_Universidad dato) {
    Nodo nuevo = new Nodo(dato);
    if (isVacio()) {
      setPrimero(nuevo);
    } else {
      Nodo puntero = Primero;
      while (puntero.Siguiente != null) {
        puntero = puntero.getSiguiente();
      }
      puntero.setSiguiente(nuevo);
    }
    Longitud++;
  }
}
```

Esa es mi lista de estudiantes, entonces a cada estudiantes quiero agregarle otra lista por ejemplos de cursos.

Como podría?

Comment: Y si la agregas como un atributo mas de tu objeto?

Comment: @jose deberias de tenerlas relaciondas en la base de datos para poder hacer lo tienes asi??